# Search folders and subfolders for a string within all Word and PDF files

Tags: python, string, pdf, ms-word, subdirectory

I'm a little new to python 2.7 and I was wondering if there was a way I could search within a folder (and all its subfolders, PDFs, and Word docs) for a certain word. I need to compile all PDF and Word files that contain a certain keyword into a new folder so I thought python might be the best way to do this instead of manually going through each file and searching for the word. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no real reason to be using Python 2 over Python 3 anymore, I'd suggest you switch over. And yes, it's possible to do that. SO isn't a code writing service, though.

Comment: the white marked packages here are the reasons not to be using python3 yet for some software http://py3readiness.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you would search a file for a word:

```
files = ["example.txt", "example2.txt", "example3.txt"]
matches = [False, False, False]
for f in range(3):
    fi = open(files[f], 'r')
    for line in fi:
        if "word" in line:
            matches[f] = True
            break
    fi.close()
print matches
```

This will open your files and check for the keyword "word". As for PDFs that will be much more difficult unless you can convert them to a text file first.

I strongly encourage you to look into tutorials, such as for looking in directories (folders), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pdf2text(pdf_file):
    return text_of_pdf_file

def word2text(doc_file):
    return text_of_doc_file

def search_word_in_path(root_path,needle):
    for current_dir,dirs,files in os.walk(root_path):
        for fname in files:
           fpath = os.path.join(current_dir,fname)
           if fpath.endswith("pdf"):
              if needle in pdf2text(fpath):
                   yield fpath
           elif fpath.endswith("doc") or fpath.endswith("docx"):
               if needle in word2text(fpath):
                    yield fpath

for filename in search_word_in_path(r"C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents","some word"):
    print("Found 'some word' in %r"%filename)
```

I guess ... I left some of the work up to you as the OP to solve